# Django manytomany field invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

Okay so i have a model for "Modules" and this model covers all fields for 4 different types of modules i can create from it.

One of the modules requires a ManyToManyField so i can store recent payments and then loop them in the template.

Here is the model for Modules:

```
class MarketModules(models.Model):
    types = (
    ('1', 'Server Status'),
    ('2', 'Recent Donations'),
    ('3', 'Donation Goal'),
    ('4', 'Textbox')
    )

    id = models.AutoField("Module id", primary_key=True, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    marketid = models.ForeignKey(Market, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField("Module type", choices=types, max_length=100, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField("Module order", default=1, blank=True, null=True)

    title = models.CharField("Module title", max_length=200, default="Module")
    text = models.CharField("Text", max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)

    goal = models.IntegerField("Monthly goal",default=100, blank=True, null=True)
    goalpercentage = models.IntegerField("Monthly percentage", default=100, blank=True, null=True)
    goalamount = models.IntegerField("Monthly amount", default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    maxDisplay = models.IntegerField("Display amount",default=5, blank=True, null=True)
    recentdonors = models.ManyToManyField(ItemsBought, null=True, blank=True)

    ip = models.CharField("Server IP", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    port = models.IntegerField("Server port", max_length=20, default=25565, blank=True, null=True)
    players = models.IntegerField("Players Online", max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    playerpercentage = models.IntegerField("Player percentage", default=100, blank=True, null=True)
    maxplayers = models.IntegerField("Max Players", max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    playersnames = models.TextField("Player Names", max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    online = models.BooleanField("Online", default=0)
    motd = models.CharField("MOTD", blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)

    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return'%s' % self.id
```

Here is the Views.py for the Edit form:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    newmodule = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if newmodule.is_valid():
        module = newmodule.save()
        if module.type == '1':
            query_server(MarketModules.objects.filter(pk=module.id))
        elif module.type == '3':
            CalGoal(MarketModules.objects.filter(pk=module.id), module.goal)
        elif module.type == '2':
            RecentDonors(module.id, module.maxDisplay)
        return redirect("/controlpanel/modules/")
else:
    newmodule = ModuleForm(instance=instance)
```

and here is the forms.py for the ModuleForm:

```
class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=CKEditorWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    title = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    ip = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    port = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    maxDisplay = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    goal = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = MarketModules

    def save(self, commit=True, owner=None, marketid=None, order=None, type=None):
        modelform = super(ModuleForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if type:
            modelform.type = type
        if order:
            modelform.order = order
        if owner:
            modelform.owner = owner
        if marketid:
            modelform.marketid = marketid
        if commit:
            modelform.save()
        return modelform
```

The issue is even though the ManytoMany Field should accept a blank for validation and should be allowed to be null when saved I keep getting the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

And if I remove `blank=True` and `null=True` I just get a validation error saying its required as expected.

How can I save the ManyToMany field being null?

TRACEBACK AS REQUESTED:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\xXxKillDogxXx\Desktop\MinecraftMarket-Redesign\market\views.py" in    EditModule
  617.             module = newmodule.save()
File "C:\Users\xXxKillDogxXx\Desktop\MinecraftMarket-Redesign\market\forms.py" in save
  99.             modelform.save()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  626.                             rows =     manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _update
  605.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1014.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  830.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  979.                 val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in     get_db_prep_save
  304.                                       prepared=False)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in     get_db_prep_value
  296.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in     get_prep_value
  991.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /controlpanel/modules/980/1/edit/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Added the traceback :)

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with M2M field? Could you provide failing data (form)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean cause it validates fine its just on the save its actually erroring out.

Comment: Also i can save it in Admin perfectly fine so could it be me overriding the save method?

Comment: managed to source it down to the goal field however im still not sure why im getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `ModuleForm` is declaring `goal` to be a `CharField`. You're telling Django that this should be a string, so when a value isn't entered the empty string (`''`) gets passed to the database layer, which is expecting an integer.

The solution is simple: `goal = forms.IntegerField(...)`. Make sure you do the same for your other fields (e.g. `port`, `maxDisplay`).